# How to generate custom report via Web service API Call?

Tags: reporting, api, marketing-cloud

I got question for you. We try to generate custom report via web service API call, but I don't know how to retrieve the data from your database. I need to generate report such as

Get all of Trigger Send total number and detail email addresses sent at date range.

We have MobiLoan account on exact target

```
 <UserName>bstevenson</UserName>
 <Password>{aPasswordGoesHere}</Password>
 <ClientId>10162725</ClientId>
```

I need to get all of trigger send emails number and send out email addresses by today or by last week. Here is an example :

```
Trigger Send name           total numver
DONothing                    28
      List all of 28 DONothing email addresses sent out by today
ForgotPassword               39
       List all of 39 ForgotPassword email addresses sent out by today
```

Could you please tell me what method of web API call and how to setup request to get all of information data?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RetrieveRequest to get the sent events.

See the details at:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieve_sentevent_details_for_job/